# Error while getting messges from sockets in javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, websocket

Hi i am having trouble with creating a socket communication from java script code.

I am always getting error while sending a message or closing the socket from server.

**My Socket server code.**

```
        // Start listening for connections.
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();
            data = null;

            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                break;
            }

            // Show the data on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

            // Echo the data back to the client.
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            handler.Send(msg);
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://Myip:11000', ['soap', 'xmpp']);    

// When the connection is open, send some data to the server
connection.onopen = function () {
    connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
    connection.send('your message');
};    
// Log errors
connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};    
connection.onclose = function (msg) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ' + msg);
};
```

It gets connected to server socket, but always gets error while closing or sending a message from server.

Answer (score 1):

If this is really your actual code:

```
handler.Send(msg);
handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
handler.Close();
```

…then it's pretty broken. First, you can't assume that Socket.Send() actually sends all the bytes you asked it to. You have to check the return value, and keep sending until you've actually sent all the data.

Second, the initiation of a graceful closure should use SocketShutdown.Send, not SocketShutdown.Both. Specifying "Both" means (among other things) that you're not going to wait for the other end to negotiate the graceful closure. That you're just done and won't even receive any more data, in addition to being done sending.

And of course, the code is calling Close() before the other end has in fact acknowledged the graceful closure (by itself sending any remaining data it wanted to send and then shutting down with "Both").

Is all this the reason for your problem? I can't say for sure, since I have no way to test your actual code. But it's certainly a reasonable guess. If you tear down the connection without waiting after you try to send something, there's not any guarantee that the data will ever leave your machine, and in any case the other end could easily see the connection reset before it gets a chance to process any data that was sent to it.

There aren't a huge number of rules when it comes to socket programming, but what rules exist are there for a reason and are generally *really* important to follow. You should make sure your code is following all the rules.

(The rest of the code is also different from what I'd consider the right way to do things, but the problems aren't entirely fatal, the way that the over-eager connection destruction is).

Comment: thanks for your response, yes you are right, i have just started with this socket programming yesterday, and haven't find any reliable sources. I will be glad if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid WebSocket does not work that way.

When the Javascript code connects to the server, it will send a HTTP request as ASCII text. That request will include a HTTP header `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: soap, xmpp`, as you are requiring those protocols in your `WebSocket` creation.

Since your server code does not reply with an appropiate HTTP response accepting the websocket connection, the connection will fail. When you try to send data back, the client will not recognize it as a HTTP response and a error will be thrown.

A websocket is not a regular socket connection, it won't work that way. It requires HTTP negotiation and there is a schema for data framing. I recommend you to go through this article that explains very well how it works: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000545/ch17.html

If you are interested in learning how to develop a server, take a look to this tutorial in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_server I also have an [open source WebSocket server in C#](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/) you can take a look if you like.